# App crash on startup when running in device

Tags: android

When I run the app it crash on startup:

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.integralblue.callerid"
android:installLocation="internalOnly" >
<!-- android:installLocation="internalOnly" because this application revolves
    around a service which would not work (and would not be restarted) if the
    application was to be installed on external storage and the storage unmounted -->

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />


<!-- required by OpenStreetMaps -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <!-- https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=310 -->

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".CallerIDApplication" android:description="@string/app_description">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="CallerID" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".PreferencesActivity" android:label="Settings" android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".CallerIDBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:exported="false" android:name=".CallerIDService" />
</application>
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs_pager);

        tabHost.setup();

        tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, tabHost, viewPager);

        tabsAdapter.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("lookup").setIndicator("Lookup",drawableTabDialer),
                LookupFragment.class, getIntent().getExtras());
        tabsAdapter.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("recentCalls").setIndicator("Recent Calls",drawableTabRecent),
                RecentCallsFragment.class, null);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(versionInformationHelper.shouldPromptForNewVersion()){
            showDialog(NEWER_VERSION_AVAILABLE_DIALOG);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("tab", tabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("lookup");

        // TODO I don't like how the fragment is retrieved - but I don't know of a better way.
        LookupFragment lookupFragment = (LookupFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + viewPager.getId() + ":" + 0);

        lookupFragment.lookup(intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.help:
                Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.integralblue.com/callerid-for-android"));
                startActivity(viewIntent);  
                return true;
            case R.id.settings:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class));  
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case NEWER_VERSION_AVAILABLE_DIALOG:
            return versionInformationHelper.createNewVersionDialog(this);
        default:
            return super.onCreateDialog(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB 09-01 12:15:39.054 13625-13651/com.integralblue.callerid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
    Process: com.integralblue.callerid, PID: 13625
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:142)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{15aa181 13625:com.integralblue.callerid/u0a396} (pid=13625, uid=10396) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4912)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6043)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2474)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1521)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:520)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompatJellybean.query(ContentResolverCompatJellybean.java:29)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat$ContentResolverCompatImplJB.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:57)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:125)
        at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:59)
        at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:37)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:296)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:42)
        at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:128)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)  09-01 12:15:39.080 13625-13625/com.integralblue.callerid D/ViewRootImpl@65b2e58[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true -321540096} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
    mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true -321540096} hwInitialized=true 09-01 12:15:39.093 13625-13625/com.integralblue.callerid D/AbsListView:  in onLayout changed  09-01 12:15:39.094 13625-13650/com.integralblue.callerid I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4 09-01 12:15:39.094 13625-13650/com.integralblue.callerid D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{15aa181 13625:com.integralblue.callerid/u0a396} (pid=13625, uid=10396) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG

Comment: add this two permission in manifest file :- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG">`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG">`

Comment: @RahulChokshi I already added those permissions to Manifest, but the app still crashing

Comment: Which android version you tested on?

Comment: @RahulChokshi android 7.0 (API 24)

Comment: @RahulChokshi Check my AndroidManifest, I just added it to the post

Comment: after marshmallow permission cycle change you have ask on runtime

Comment: @RahulChokshi so what should I do?

Comment: u can change the target api (change to <= 21) or get permission in runtime for API 24

Answer (score 1):

You need to set runtime permissions.

```
String wantPermission = Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG;
// called in a standard activity, use ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission for AppCompActivity
int permissionCheck = checkSelfPermission(this, wantPermission);
if (!permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // user may have declined earlier, ask Android if we should show him a reason
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, wantPermission)) {
        // show an explanation to the user
    } else {
        // request the permission.
        // CALLBACK_NUMBER is a integer constants
        requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,  new String[]{wantPermission}, CALLBACK_NUMBER);
    }
} else {
    // got permission, use it
}
```

Same for write call log

Your MainActivity should like this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs_pager);
            permissions();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(versionInformationHelper.shouldPromptForNewVersion()){
            showDialog(NEWER_VERSION_AVAILABLE_DIALOG);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("tab", tabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("lookup");

        // TODO I don't like how the fragment is retrieved - but I don't know of a better way.
        LookupFragment lookupFragment = (LookupFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + viewPager.getId() + ":" + 0);

        lookupFragment.lookup(intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.help:
                Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.integralblue.com/callerid-for-android"));
                startActivity(viewIntent);  
                return true;
            case R.id.settings:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class));  
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case NEWER_VERSION_AVAILABLE_DIALOG:
            return versionInformationHelper.createNewVersionDialog(this);
        default:
            return super.onCreateDialog(id);
        }
    }
}

public void permissions()
{
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Permission is not granted
    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)) {
        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
    } else {
        // No explanation needed; request the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
} else {
    // Permission has already been granted
        init();
}
}

public void init()
{

            tabHost.setup();

            tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, tabHost, viewPager);

            tabsAdapter.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("lookup").setIndicator("Lookup",drawableTabDialer),
                    LookupFragment.class, getIntent().getExtras());
            tabsAdapter.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("recentCalls").setIndicator("Recent Calls",drawableTabRecent),
                    RecentCallsFragment.class, null);

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
            }
}
```

Comment: where should I add that exactly?

Comment: on onCreate method. For more info read this : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview and this: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java

Comment: kindly accept my answer if it work for you or if not then let me know what error or problem your are facing.

Comment: Didn't work for me, can you please put MainActivity code with those modifications?

Comment: I got those errors! error: cannot find symbol variable thisActivity / error: package Manifest does not exist
 / error: cannot find symbol variable ContextCompat
 / error: cannot find symbol variable PackageManager

Comment: press alt+enter and import them